# Make appear hypertarget labels in PDF

Tags: hyperref, pdf

Some time ago (TeX Live 2013), xelatex stored labels of hypertarget in PDFs. Then (at least in TeX Live 2016) the behaviour was changed, there are no more symbolic names inside.

How can I get the names back?

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[verbose]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
An anchor for postprocessing:
\hypertarget{ID01234567}{}
\end{document}
```

After the document is compiled with xelatex, I review the internals:

```
$ qpdf --stream-data=uncompress test.pdf - | gvim -
```

What I want is to find:

```
<< /Names [ (Doc-Start) 7 0 R (ID01234567) 8 0 R (page.1) 9 0 R ] >>
```

I get the desired result with TeX Live 2013, but not 2016.

## 30 July 2018, update

I've generated XDV (instead of PDF) on a newer system and converted XDV to PDF on an older system. I've got the destinations. So, the problems are, most likely, in `dvipdfm`. Here is a changelog for later investigation:
http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Build/source/texk/dvipdfm-x/spc_pdfm.c?view=log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented as a incompatible change in section 11 of the `dvipdfmx` manual. The bit position `5` for the `-C` option can be used to disable optimizing PDF destinations. The count starts with `1`, so bit position `5` corresponds to `16`. You can pass this flag when calling XeLaTeX with

```
 xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -C 16" test.tex
```

If you use Windows, you might need another way to quote the command.